# Docking a java application jna on windows

Tags: java, jna, dock, shell32

I'm trying to build a Windows dockable application that reserves a section of the screen to prevent other applications from show in that space.

I have try using JNI and JNA. The code above shows how far I have got.

```
package jnadock;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.ShellAPI;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.ShellAPI.APPBARDATA;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.UINT_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JNADock {

private HWND hWndGlobal;
private final String frameTitle = "Dockable frame";

public interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    final static Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    public Shell32 INSTANCE = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("Shell32", Shell32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);

    UINT_PTR SHAppBarMessage(DWORD dwMessage, APPBARDATA pData);

}

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    final static Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);

    boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);

    int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

    HWND FindWindowA(String winClass, String title);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JNADock jna = new JNADock();
}

public JNADock() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(frameTitle);
    frame.setSize(600, 100);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            appbarRemove();
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    appbarSetPos();


    final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;

    hWndGlobal = user32.FindWindowA(null, frameTitle);

    appbarNew() ;
    appbarSetPos();
    frame.setLocation(0,0);
}

 private void appbarNew() {

    APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA.ByReference();
    data.cbSize.setValue(data.size());
    int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    data.hWnd = hWndGlobal;
    data.uCallbackMessage.setValue(WM_USER + 1);

    UINT_PTR result = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHAppBarMessage(new DWORD(ShellAPI.ABM_NEW), data);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
}

private void appbarSetPos() {
    APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA.ByReference();
    data.cbSize.setValue(data.size());
    data.uEdge.setValue(ShellAPI.ABE_TOP);

    data.rc.top = 0;
    data.rc.left = 0;
    data.rc.bottom = 100;
    data.rc.top = 600;

    UINT_PTR result = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHAppBarMessage(new DWORD(ShellAPI.ABM_SETPOS), data);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
}

private void appbarRemove(){
    APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA.ByReference();
    data.cbSize.setValue(data.size());
    int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    data.hWnd = hWndGlobal;
    data.uCallbackMessage.setValue(WM_USER + 1);

    UINT_PTR result = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHAppBarMessage(new DWORD(ShellAPI.ABM_REMOVE), data);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
}
}
```

When executed, the frame is shown but no error or hint of what I'm doing wrong is printed.

Note that I just started using JNA and I could be committing rookie mistakes. Feel free to smoke them out.

Comment: Your `User32` library should be initialized the same way as `Shell32`.  You may find it easier to simply derive from the versions of those libraries provided in JNA's `platform.jar`.

Comment: @technomage Done, but I'm not following you when you say "simply derive from the versions of those libraries provided". Again excuse my lack of experience on this field.

Comment: JNA provides versions of Shell32, User32, et al. in its platform.jar package.  If you derive your library interface from those, you have fewer interface methods to define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call `SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETPOS)` you have to initialize a new AppBar calling `SHAppBarMessage(ABM_NEW)`as show below.

```
 private void appbarNew() {

    APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA.ByReference();
    data.cbSize.setValue(data.size());
    int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    data.hWnd = hWndGlobal;
    data.uCallbackMessage.setValue(WM_USER + 1);

    UINT_PTR result = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHAppBarMessage(new DWORD(ShellAPI.ABM_NEW), data);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);

}
```

At the end don't forget to remove the new AppBar calling `SHAppBarMessage(ABM_REMOVE)`

---

[Related docs from Microsoft Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but still doesn't work as expected. I have updated the code. Im getting 0 when trying ABM_NEW.

Comment: I've published the code snippet that i've successfully tested here https://gist.github.com/681fb27eea39404e86c5.git - Win7(64bit) - Java6 - jna-platform 4.1.0