# make a jframe on top of a screen and other os windows to maximize below it

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the following swing code :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameDemo {

    private JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

    public JFrameDemo() {
        jframe.setSize(new Dimension(800, 20));
        jframe.setUndecorated(true);
        jframe.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("xxxxxxxxxxx"));
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        jframe.setLocation(0, 0);

        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        jframe.setMaximizedBounds(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());
        jframe.toFront();
        jframe.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFrameDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My `jframe` window is always on  top and also in the top of the screen but when other window from os ,like a browser window, is maximized my `jframe` overlaps that window . 
When  any os windows are maximized to be maximized below my `jframe` window.
you can see:

**WRONG Behavior**

---

[image: current_wrong_behavior.png]

**GOOD Behavior**

---

[image: wanted_good_behavior.png]

Since I understood java has no support for that feature so I am asking now if exists any native library which should I load using the jni.

Comment: Fortunately, Java does not provide such functionality.

Comment: do you know any workaround ?

Comment: Yep. Write an app. that is ***not*** bloody irritating in that it presumes to affect how other apps. maximize!

Comment: I not want to affect how other apps works, I just want that my app to have the same behavior like a windows toolbar positioned at the top of the screen.

Comment: The OS is (presumably) under that control of the end user. The only thing they can, and probably will, do with your app. is uninstall it.

Comment: just trying to make an application like: http://www.battware.co.uk/desktopticker_downloads.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the behavior that I am looking for can be made using the jna lib: [Docking a java application jna on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301979/docking-a-java-application-jna-on-windows)