# Can Java cause Windows split screen?

Tags: java, windows, swing

### Context

---

In Microsoft Windows, I am able make an application's window occupy half the of display by using the shortcuts:

- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

These shortcuts cause a "split screen," as seen in this screenshot:

[image: split screen]

I would like to programmatically size and position a [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) in the same manner. However, I do not know how to achieve the desired result.

I thought that solution was:

1. Set the frame's width to the half the screen width.
2. Set the frame's height to the screen height (minus the taskbar height).
3. Set the frame's position to (0,0).

Here is an MCVE:

```
JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();

Rectangle windowBounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
testFrame.setSize(windowBounds.width / 2, windowBounds.height);
testFrame.setLocation((int) windowBounds.getMinX(), (int) windowBounds.getMinY());

testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
testFrame.setVisible(true);
```

This nearly works, but the window has small margins on the bottom and the left:

[image]

### Question

---

On a Windows computer, is there a way to programmatically split the screen using Java, or perhaps JNI?

Comment: Print the values of `windowBounds.getMinX()` and `windowBounds.getMinY()`, as well as `getMaximumWindowBounds()`, and make sure they're reasonable.

Comment: Why do you want to do it yourself? If the users of your program want to do it with your program they can do it without special support from your program - it is Windows that does it with the programs.

Comment: You're talking about an operation which is controlled by the OS, why do you feel the need to replicate it in your code?

Comment: You probably want testFrame.[setExtendedWindowState](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int))(Frame.MAXIMIZED_VERT).

Comment: @ThomasKläger The functionality was requested for an application within my company. I personally think this is *solving a problem that doesn't exist* but the company wants a button to split the screen (since keyboard shortcuts are allegedly too difficult for "non technically minded" people to learn).

Comment: @MadProgrammer see above comment ^

Comment: @CardinalSystem *"since keyboard shortcuts are allegedly too difficult for "non technically minded" people to learn"* - there comes a point in time when if some is to "dumb" you stop catering for them.  The short cut keys are universal to Windows (like since Windows 7?!?), so I'm sure they'd be overjoyed to learn of them, as it would make their  everyday lives so much easier

Comment: [Docking a java application jna on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301979/docking-a-java-application-jna-on-windows)

Comment: If you add in to your application then people will have problems adding another application to the other half of the screen. If you educate them they can use this feature with all applications. And snapping to either the left or right half of the screen is only part of the feature that Windows supports: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241 - do you really want to add all those options to your application?

Comment: @StephenC this is an internal application where the end-users are our own employees. I think your recommendation may be a suitable alternative to automatically splitting the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround that achieved [what I believe to be] your desired result.
(Oracle JDK 21 on Windows 10)

- Initially set the `JFrame` to be maximized, i.e. take up the whole screen.
- Add a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the `JFrame`.
- When the `JFrame` is displayed on the [computer] screen, adjust its size.
  (Method `windowOpened` is called only once – when the window is initially displayed.)

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TstFrame extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override // java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event) {
        Window window = event.getWindow();
        Dimension dim = window.getSize();
        window.setSize(dim.width / 2, dim.height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
            testFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            testFrame.addWindowListener(new TstFrame());
            testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            testFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Screen capture:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: This comes close enough to the desired behavior. Thank for answering rather than lecturing! Just trying to do my job here :P

Answer (score 0):

You are in a highly volatile area. Depending on user preferences the values for margin width, taskbar height/width or other settings may vary. Unless you use the 'Window Manager' function to position the window you will run a lottery of having the right values. Doing that from Java may require to involve JNI and the correct Win32 API call.

Hence I'd try to avoid that situation. Why do you need it at all? And could it help if your application saved the window position and size upon exit, so it can remember them when starting up next time? Then the user can still choose where to have the window while he is not fixed on the left or right half of the screen.